# jshint ignore Use '!==' to compare with ''

Tags: javascript, jshint

How can I configure JSHint to ignore this error: `Use '!==' to compare with ''.` ?

I want that this code pass:

```
/*jshint undef: false */
if (a == true) {

}
```

Comment: What version of JSHint are you using? If you use the 1.0.0 release candidate, you can use the new "ignore any warning" options, which is this case would simply be `/*jshint -W047 */`.

Comment: cool thanks, I'm using 0.9.1. I will try the RC

Comment: it's acutally -W041 but install the new rc was a nice tips thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, yeah, W041. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is to install the new version of jshint:

`npm install -g https://github.com/jshint/jshint/archive/1.0.0-rc4.tar.gz`

Then to use this config:

```
{
    "-W041": false
}
```

Finally this command

`jshint --config jshint.json file.js`

Comment: No (or at least, not with the current version).

Answer (score 6):

Just use:

```
if (a) {

}
```

You don't *ever* need to use `== true` in a `if` statement.

Comment: @charles I'm just curious, in what situation would code that you can't modify _need_ to pass JSHint?

Comment: Because it's too much to modify. I want to minify the javascript but there is a synthax error in the file and the minify tool doesn't give any line where this error is ...

Comment: @Cerbrus, I don't think that is accurate to say that you don't *ever* need to use `== true` in an `if` statement. That's not entirely true. If you want to verify that not only the variable is truthy but it's actually a boolean value of true, then this would be perfectly acceptable, no?

Comment: for that you would use === true, no?

Comment: @kentcdodds: `==` doesn't check type. You'd use `===` to check if it's a boolean with the value `true`