# JSHint ignore Use '===' to compare with 'true'

Tags: javascript, jshint

How can I configure JSHint to ignore this error: `Use '===' to compare with 'true'` ?\

My code is,

```
if (something == true){
    //code
}
```

I want the condition to pass if `something` is `1` or `true`. The first error I got was `Expected '===' and instead saw '=='`. So, I added `/*jslint eqeq: true*/` comment above the `if` condition. After that I am getting the above mentioned error. How to suppress both the errors?

EDIT:

Changing the condition from `if (something == true)` to `if (something)` will solve the problem, but I don't want to edit the condition. Is there anyway to suppress the error without changing the condition?

Comment: just do `if (something){  /* code */ }`

Comment: @w0lf Sorry for not mentioned it. I don't want to change the condition. Without changing the code I want to suppress the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jshint ignore Use '!==' to compare with ''](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895217/jshint-ignore-use-to-compare-with)

Comment: @w0lf This is not the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895217/jshint-ignore-use-to-compare-with I referred it first. I don't want to change the condition, I want to suppress the error

Comment: I think this does answer the question (suppresses the error without changing the code): http://stackoverflow.com/a/14895829/390819

Comment: If you read the accepted answer to it there would be a solution posted in that Question which doesn't require you to change the condition. Does that solution not work for you? Furthermore if you are willing to change the code around the `if` by adding a comment why not just change the condition as it could be considered to be wrong the way it is?